# How to serialize a simple object for Chronicle Queue using Chronicle Wire

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue, chronicle-wire

I currently put my objects in the Chronicle Queue as follows

```
ExcerptAppender appender = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder
                .binary("/path_to_chronicle/")
                .build()
                .acquireAppender();

// Write
synchronized (appender) {
    appender.writeText(object.toString());
}
```

Considering the class of "object" is extending AbstractMarshallable and has some ints, longs and strings, is there a more efficent way to pass it on to the queue? The way I currently read it off the queue is by calling `Marshallable.fromString(text);`. I'm looking for a simple use case without too much code but still fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For writing, I would suggest you follow

```
try (final DocumentContext dc = appender.writingDocument()) {
      dc.wire().write("msg").object(object);
}
```

and reading

```
try (DocumentContext dc = tailer.readingDocument()) {
    if (dc.isPresent()) {
        Object o = dc.wire().read("msg").object();
        process(o);
    }
}
```

This can be made more efficient, but it will be faster than what you have.